# wordpress homepage margintop in html

Tags: wordpress

There is a margin-top 32px for the html in my wordpress site.
I added:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

in the functions.php
then the 32px was removed from all pages except the homepage.

I opened the site from other browser too, and after logging out from the wordpress dashboard.

please help, how can I remove the 32px margin-top from the homepage too.

Comment: Hi merryxian
you can remove the margin-top through CSS.
The code you are using is just to remove the **Admin bar** from front-end.

Comment: @YogeshGarg I tried through CSS by setting html {margin-top:0px;} but it didnt work

Comment: try this:
    html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
 * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }

Comment: @merryxian please share your website link.

Comment: sorry this site is in localhost